# Kintoneカスタマイズでポータル画面のappIDが知りたい

Tags: javascript

###### 質問内容

提示コードですが以下の`kintone`のポータル画面をカスタマイズしたいのですがローカルファイルのアップロードを自動で行ってほしいのですが`appID`なるものが必要でその`ID`がわかりません。提示コードのように画面にコンソール出力させましたが`null`という表示されています。これはどうしたらいいのでしょか？

###### 知りたいこと

kintonのポータル画面でのappIDの取得方法
もしくはポータル画面の編集で自動でローカルファイルをアップロードして更新してくれる仕組みを導入する方法が知りたい。

###### 試したこと

提示の`upload-manifest.json`の`app`のところにブラウザ上でのポータル画面でのURLに`k`,`#`などと書いてあっため`k,#,あと0,null,""`等を入れて試しましたが設定できません。

###### アップロードコマンド

```
npx kintone-customize-uploader ./upload-manifest.json --watch
```

###### コンソールログ

```
Hello World
Hello World
Hello World
null
```

###### upload-manifest.json

```js
{
    "app": "0",
    "scope": "ALL",
    "desktop": {
        "js": [
            "./Index.js"
        ],
        "css": []
    },
    "mobile": {
        "js": []
    }
}
```

###### Index.js

```js
"use strict";
(() => {
    console.log("Hello World");
    console.log("Hello World");
    console.log("Hello World");

    kintone.events.on('portal.show', () => 
    {
        console.log(kintone.app.getId());
    });

    kintone.events.on("app.record.create.show", (event) => {
        const appId = event.appId;
        const recordId = event.recordId;
    });
})();
```

Answer (score 0):

「kintone appid 確認」でGoogle検索すると以下の記事がヒットします。

[kintone連携 アプリIDの確認](https://support.kincone.com/hc/ja/articles/4411880749081-kintone%E9%80%A3%E6%90%BA-%E3%82%A2%E3%83%97%E3%83%AAID%E3%81%AE%E7%A2%BA%E8%AA%8D)

> kintoneのアプリ画面を開き、URLを確認してください。
> 「https://[サブドメイン].cybozu.com/k/」に続いて表示されている末尾の数字がアプリIDです。
>
> [image]

Comment: ありがとうございます。自分の画面ではなぜかhttps://xxxxx.cybozu.com/k/#/portalと表示されるのですがそれはアプリ画面ではないでしょうか？自分が知りたいのはポータル画面です。回答を踏まえるとやはり#ということでしょうか？

Comment: 質問そのものが kintone のヘルプを確認したり、kintone のサポートに問い合わせるべき内容に思えます。